# Difference between be settled down and settle down?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

> He has finally settled down.
>
> He is finally settled down.

Does second one mean that the guy has married and started a good life?
What about the first one? Which one would you prefer most?

Comment: The first one reads naturally. The second one is odd, because "settled down" is not usually used attributively like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it depends on a bit more context, but *He has finally settled down* usually means found a stable place in life, like getting married as you mentioned.

However, it can also mean he was very upset, like after witnessing a tragedy or losing a loved one, and has finally *calmed down*.